# Why localStreams contains LocalMediaStream and remoteStreams contains MediaStream?

Tags: webrtc

[image]

**localStreams** and **remoteStreams** both are of type “**MediaStreamList**”.
**localStreams** contains “**LocalMediaStream**” objects

However, **remoteStreams** contains “**MediaStream**” objects

*Why so difference?*

When I use “**localStreams**” – it works for me:

```
localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(localStreams[0]);
```

But if I try to use “**remoteStreams**” – it doesn’t work:

```
remoteVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(remoteStreams[0])
```

**Blobs** for “**remoteStreams**” and “**localStreams**” are looking same in style.

Why “**remoteStreams**” doesn’t work for me (in “**onaddstream**” event or directly) ???

```
remoteVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(secondPeer.remoteStreams[0])
"blob:http%3A//localhost%3A8082/78e8821f-90b8-4703-b56d-918ec505e5bf"
```

**Live Demo**:--- https://muazkh.appspot.com/?page=WebRTC

Answer (score 0):

LocalMediaStream is being replaced by the MediaStream interface.

On [simpl.info/pc](http://simpl.info/rtcpeerconnection/), try this from the console in Chrome Stable and Canary:

```
localPeerConnection.getLocalStreams()[0];
remotePeerConnection.getRemoteStreams()[0];
```

Comment: It means that "remote streams attachment" is possible, Sam, for further forwarding? It failed all the time. Experiment shows that it is still failing: https://googledrive.com/host/0B6GWd_dUUTT8V1Fodm9WQldkb28/Attaching-Remote-MediaStreams.html ----- sorry for out of topic question.

Comment: Hi Sam and @MuazKhan the `getRemoteStreams` is now deprecating, do we have work around method?

Comment: Hi @Xin — take a look at https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints for an alternative (do it yourself!) approach. Also in adapter.js: https://github.com/webrtc/adapter/blob/b5100538591ce6938e24d7912dbba9ebb938ecfb/release/adapter.js#L400

Comment: Hi @Xin, you can use "peer.getReceivers()". You will get two MediaStreamTrack objects using "receiver.track" property. Now you can merge these tracks using "new MediaStream([track1, track1])" or "stream.addTrack". Example: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/webrtcpedia/#getremotestreams-alternative

Comment: Thank you very much